# How to set article page depth?

Tags: formatting, page, depth

In order for the publication of an article in a journal the format requirements asked to me are to use 'article' format with text width set to 125 mm and the page depth to 185 mm.

I am using

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\setlength{\textwidth}{125mm}
```

but I can't figure out how to satisfy the page depth requirement.Any suggestion?

Comment: `article` not `amsart` (if that is what they asked for) and  set `\textheight`

Comment: Thanks, however they don't complain about the use of `amsart`. Is there any reason about avoiding its use with `textwidht` and `textheight`?

Comment: no  they are core latex lengths and will work the same way in any class.